# Why does not change the image size in a sized unordered list?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a simple gallery.
I set up the `width` and `height` of `li` and the `img` size, but it doesn't fit.
I want to make unified image sizes.
What's wrong with my code?

```css
body
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: black;
  font-family: sans-serif, Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  
}

.container
{
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}

.container a
{
  background: #ccc;
  color: #666;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background 0.5s, color 0,5s;
}

.container a:hover
{
  background: #aaa;
  color: #fff;
}
main 
{
  background: #111;
  padding: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/*Gallery*/

.gallery 
{
  background: #999;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.gallery li
{
  background: red;
  width: 31%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  height: 175px;
  
}

.gallery img
{
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}


.container .gallery a
{
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta lang="hu">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="res/teszt.css">
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <!-- FEJLÉC -->
    
  <div class="container">
      <main>
        <ul class="gallery">
          <li>
            <a href="https://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/29/92/9VWQiO.jpg" target="_blank">
              <img src="https://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/29/92/9VWQiO.jpg" alt="">
              <span>lorem ipsim</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a2/1121098-pink-nature-wallpaper-1920x1080-lockscreen.jpg" target="_blank">
              <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a2/1121098-pink-nature-wallpaper-1920x1080-lockscreen.jpg" alt="">
              <span>lorem ipsim</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://images.template.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/27043339/Nature-Wallpaper1.jpg" target="_blank">
              <img src="https://images.template.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/27043339/Nature-Wallpaper1.jpg" alt="">
              <span>lorem ipsim</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/255959.jpg" target="_blank">
              <img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/255959.jpg" alt="">
              <span>lorem ipsim</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp4013939.jpg" target="_blank">
              <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp4013939.jpg" alt="">
              <span>lorem ipsim</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://images.hdqwalls.com/wallpapers/best-nature-image.jpg" target="_blank">
              <img src="https://images.hdqwalls.com/wallpapers/best-nature-image.jpg" alt="">
              <span>lorem ipsim</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </main>

    </div>
    
  </body>


</html>
```

Comment: Please ask your question more clear and add more details. I have troubles understanding what you trying to do or to achieve.

Answer (score -2):

Just define some height and width to image it will start working.

```css
body
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: black;
  font-family: sans-serif, Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  
}

.container
{
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}

.container a
{
  background: #ccc;
  color: #666;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background 0.5s, color 0,5s;
}

.container a:hover
{
  background: #aaa;
  color: #fff;
}
main 
{
  background: #111;
  padding: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/*Gallery*/

.gallery 
{
  background: #999;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.gallery li
{
  background: red;
  width: 31%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  height: 175px;
  
}

.gallery img
{
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}


.container .gallery a
{
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%; 
  background-size: cover;


  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta lang="hu">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="res/teszt.css">
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <!-- FEJLÉC -->
    
  <div class="container">
      <main>
        <ul class="gallery">
          <li>
            <a href="https://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/29/92/9VWQiO.jpg" target="_blank">
              <img src="https://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/29/92/9VWQiO.jpg" alt="">
              <span>lorem ipsim</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a2/1121098-pink-nature-wallpaper-1920x1080-lockscreen.jpg" target="_blank">
              <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a2/1121098-pink-nature-wallpaper-1920x1080-lockscreen.jpg" alt="">
              <span>lorem ipsim</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://images.template.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/27043339/Nature-Wallpaper1.jpg" target="_blank">
              <img src="https://images.template.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/27043339/Nature-Wallpaper1.jpg" alt="">
              <span>lorem ipsim</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/255959.jpg" target="_blank">
              <img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/255959.jpg" alt="">
              <span>lorem ipsim</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp4013939.jpg" target="_blank">
              <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp4013939.jpg" alt="">
              <span>lorem ipsim</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://images.hdqwalls.com/wallpapers/best-nature-image.jpg" target="_blank">
              <img src="https://images.hdqwalls.com/wallpapers/best-nature-image.jpg" alt="">
              <span>lorem ipsim</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </main>

    </div>
    
  </body>


</html>
```

Comment: Asker already has height and width set on images via CSS.

Comment: You need to particularly define a height for an image. In order to change it according to needs. I did there you can check that out. In My code snippet i changed here .container .gallery a
{
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;

Comment: Again, asker already has height set for images.

Comment: I set it there right now here .container .gallery a

Comment: That's not the image. That's the image container.

Comment: My love Image has also boundaries which you have to define according to div boundaries.

Comment: Sorry @Ouroborus I thought you are the asker I am kind of new here that's why I don't able to distinguish between you and asker and that's why I behaved like that sorry

Comment: @ashir Then I suggest you [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site.

Comment: Yah I Should...